# Prove that the number of conjugacy classes of a finite group $G$ is given by $ k(G) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}{\left|C(g)\right|} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is really bothering me. I feel like I have the right idea, but I can't get it to work.

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Prove that the number of conjugacy classes of a finite group $G$ is given by

$$ k(G) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}{\left|C(g)\right|} \qquad (*) $$

using the fact that $\left|G/C(g)\right|$ is the size of the conjugacy class of $g$.

**Where I Am:**

Ok. Since the conjugacy classes partition $G$, we have that

$$ |G| = \sum_{g \in G}{\left|G/C(g)\right|}. $$

Furthermore, we can represent the order of $G$ as the average size of its conjugacy classes multiplied by the number of conjugacy classes (this is to bring $k(G)$ into the picture):

$$ |G| = k(G) \cdot \frac{1}{k(G)} \sum_{g \in G}{\left|G/C(g)\right|}. $$

And, since each $C(g)$ is a subgroup of $G$, we can use Lagrange's Theorem to get

$$ \sum_{g \in G}{\left|G/C(g)\right|} = \sum_{g \in G}{\left|G\right|/\left|C(g)\right|} = \frac{\left|G \right|}{\sum_{g \in G}{\left| C(g) \right|}} $$

since the order of $G$ is obviously a constant.

So, I feel like everything I've stated is valid, and yet these can't be put together to get $(*)$, for some reason. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to review how to add fractions.

Comment: What David Hill is alluding to is your last equality.

Comment: @Nex Ah, yes. I see now. I can't do that with the summation. Ok, back to the drawing board, I guess...

Comment: This is also an easy consequence of Burnside's theorem, since the number of conjugacy classes is the number of orbits of $G$ acting on itself by conjugation, and the set of points fixed by an element $g$ of $G$ is equal to $C_G(g)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathcal{O}(g)$ denote the conjugacy class of $g\in G$. Define
$$
f_{gh}=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{if }ghg^{-1}=h\\
0&\mbox{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
Now,
$$\sum_g f_{gh}=|C(h)|.$$
Since $|C(h)|=|C(h')|$ for $h'\in\mathcal{O}(h)$, we have
$$\sum_{h'\in\mathcal{O}(h)}\sum_g f_{gh'}=|\mathcal{O}(h)||C(h)|=|G|$$
Let $\Gamma$ be a set of representative of distinct conjugacy classes in $G$, so $|\Gamma|=k(G)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{h\in G}|C(h)|&=\sum_{g,h\in G}f_{gh}\\
&=\sum_{h\in\Gamma}\left(\sum_{h'\in\mathcal{O}(h)}\sum_{g\in G}f_{gh'}\right)\\
&=\sum_{h\in \Gamma}|G|\\
&=k(G)|G|
\end{align*}
This proves the claim.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a much easier way to solve this question:

> **Theorem(Burnside's lemma):** if X is a finite G-set and N is the number of orbits of X, then:
> $$N= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum F(g)$$
> where g $\in$ G and F(g) denotes the number of points in X that g fixes.

since this is a known theorem in abstract algebra, I'm not going to prove it.

Now assuming the theorem holds, let G act on itself by conjugation.

Completing the conclusion is left to you as an exercise.