# Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$ and prove the following $ k(G) \le \left|G / H\right|\cdot k(H) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$ and prove the following

$$ k(G) \le \left|G / H\right|\cdot k(H) $$

using the fact that for a finite group $A$, the number of conjugacy classes of $A$ is given by

$$ k(A) = \frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{a \in A}{\left|C(a)\right|} $$

**Where I Am:**

Well, just applying the "fact," I get...

$$ \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}{|C(g)|} \le |G/H|\cdot \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{h \in H}{|C(h)|} $$

and then by Lagrange's Theorem...

$$ \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}{|C(g)|} \le \frac{|G|}{|H|}\cdot \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{h \in H}{|C(h)|} $$

and then multiplying both sides by $|G|$...

$$ \sum_{g \in G}{|C(g)|} \le \left(\frac{|G|}{|H|}\right)^2\cdot  \sum_{h \in H}{|C(h)|} $$

which, I suppose, makes intuitive sense, but I'll be damned if I can make any progress beyond that. If $H$ were normal, it'd be a different story, but we don't have that assumption. If any one can provide any help here, it'd be greatly appreciated!

(EDIT: More steps included.)

Comment: What is $k(G)$?

Comment: @Bernard The number of conjugacy classes of $G$.

Comment: Where do you get $ k(A) = \frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{a \in A}{\left|C(a)\right|} $? From class equation, we can't get it.

Comment: @hermes It's actually a special case of Burnside's Lemma. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499013/prove-that-the-number-of-conjugacy-classes-of-a-finite-group-g-is-given-by-k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final inequality has a neat reinterpretation: it says that if you pick two elements at random, the probability that they commute is larger in the smaller group.

As for the actual question, I found the following argument in [this 1970 paper by Gallagher.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01113339#page-1) Observe that $[H:C_H(x)]\le [G: C_G(x)]$; this simply expresses the trivial fact that the orbit of $x$ under the conjugation action of $H$ is not larger than when $G\supseteq H$ acts. Rearranging we obtain that $|C_G(x)|\le [G:H]|C_H(x)|$. Thus
$$
\sum_{x\in G} |C_G(x)| \le [G:H] \sum_{x\in G} |C_H(x)| =[G:H] \sum_{h\in H} |C_G(h)|\le [G:H]^2 \sum_{h\in H} |C_H(h)| ,
$$
as desired.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from the sum over $g$ to the sum over $h$ in your middle equality. Are you asserting that $|C_H(x)|=0$ if $x\notin H$?

Comment: No. $\sum_{x\in G} |C_H(x)| = \sum_{x\in G, h\in H} f(x,h)$, where $f(x,h)=1$ if $x,h$ commute and $=0$ otherwise. Now change the order of summation.

Comment: Why the downvote, by the way?

Comment: You made a typo in your comment above. You want $\sum_{g\in G}|C_H(x)|=\sum_{g\in G, h\in H}f(x,h)$. Now you use $f(x,h)=f(h,x)$ to get the equality. This is a nontrivial step in the proof, but for some reason you didn't explain it. I recommend editing your answer.

Comment: Well, anyone who stumbles over it can just read the comments now. And yes, I guess I do use that $x$ and $h$ commute if and only if $h$ and $x$ commute, but isn't this getting a little pedantic?