# Relationships between number of conjugacy classes of a group and of a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**The statement of the problem:**

Given a finite group $G$ and a subgroup $H$, I need to show that the number of conjugacy classes of $G$,

$$
k(G) \leq |G / H|\,k(H)
$$

where $k(H)$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $H$.

**Where I Am:**

Applying the orbit counting formula to both $G$ and $H$, I've already shown a similar statement:

$$
k(H) \leq |G / H|\,k(G).
$$

However, I'm really stuck on how to proceed for the first one. Could it have something to do with counting the orbits of $G/H$? If so, again using the orbit counting formula, the expression I need to show seems to be equivalent to

$$
|G|\sum_{g \in G} |C(g)| \leq \frac{|H|}{k(G/H)}\left[\sum_{gH \in G / H}|C(gH)|\right]\left[\sum_{h \in H}|C(h)|\right]
$$

in which $C(x)$ denotes the centraliser of $x$. Here, it seems like $|G|$ could certainly be related to the fraction on the RHS, and the inequality between the sums seems intuitive, but I feel like things are getting needlessly complex.

Any help would be great.

Comment: This seems to be the same question as this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502120/let-h-be-a-subgroup-of-a-finite-group-g-and-prove-the-following-kg-le

Answer (score 1):

Using The Orbit Counting Theorem, I was able to get this problem down to $$ \frac{\sum_{g \in G} C(g)}{\sum_{h \in H} C(h)}=\frac{|G|^2}{|H|^2} $$

But I'm not sure what the relationship is between the centralizers and the order of a group.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{C_1,...,C_r\}$ be the set of all conjugacy classes of $G$ that intersect $H$ non-trivially. Since every $C_i$ is a union of $t_i$ conjugacy classes of $H$, we have $$|H| \le t_1 |C_1| + ... + t_r|C_r| \le r\sum\limits_{i = 1}^r {|{C_i}|} .$$ Also, $$G = k(G)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^k {|{C_i}|}.$$ Therefore we can write

$$\frac{{|G|}}{{|H|}}{\rm{ \ge }}\frac{{k(G)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^k {|{C_i}|} }}{{r\sum\limits_{i = 1}^r {|{C_i}|} }}{\rm{ \ge }}\frac{{k(G)}}{r}{\rm{ \ge }}\frac{{k(G)}}{{k(H)}}.$$