# The number of conjugacy classes of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$\textbf{Sorry, I have a question:}$

> > Suppose that $H$ is an Abelian subgroup of the group $G$. How can we show that $G$ has at least $\frac{|H|^2}{|G|}$ conjugacy classes.

We know that the number of conjugacy classes of a finite group $G$ is given by $k(G) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}{\left|C(g)\right|} $; [link to the result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499013/prove-that-the-number-of-conjugacy-classes-of-a-finite-group-g-is-given-by-k).

And also we know that $H \le C_G(H)$ if and only if $H$ is Abelian, because suppose $H \le C_G(H) = \{g \in G \mid gh = hg ~~\forall h \in H \}$. This means every $g \in H$ satisfies $gh = hg$ for all $h \in H$. Consequently $H$ is Abelian.

And conversely suppose $H$ is Abelian. Take any $g \in H$. We claim $g \in C_G(H)$. Because $H$ is Abelian it follows that $gh = hg$ for all $h \in H$. This means $g \in C_G(H) = \{g \in G \mid gh = hg ~~ \forall h \in H \}$. Thus
$H \le C_G(H)$.

Now it is supposed by knowing these results we find the result asked in this question. But I still cannot see it!

Can someone let me know how can we show the result?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be better not to apologize for having a question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ is $$k(G) := \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} |C(g)|$$ where $C(g)$ denotes the subgroup of elements in $G$ commuting with $g$. Note that since $H$ is abelian, for any $h \in H$ we have $H \le C(h)$, hence $|C(h)| \ge |H|$. Thus, $$\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} |C(g)| = \frac{1}{|G|} \left(\sum_{h\in H} |C(h)| + \sum_{g\not\in H} |C(g)| \right) \ge \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{h\in H} |H| = \frac{|H|^2}{|G|}$$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Sorry, I think in the third line you mean $|C(h)| \ge |H|$? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I've fixed it now.

Comment: Many thanks! Sorry I have one more question. For to get $H \le C(h)$ you used $H \le C_G(H)$?

Comment: Since $H$ is abelian, if $h \in H$, every element of $H$ commutes with $h$, hence $H \le C(h)$. This also certainly follows from your observation that $H \le C_{G} (H)$ since $C_{G}(H)$ is the subgroup of things commuting with *everything* in $H$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!